# Referencing by an object type Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to reference an object by it's type in Java?

For example, I have this:

```
private static class Pet {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Pet setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

public static class CAT extends Pet{}

public static class DOG extends Pet{}
```

I put a bunch of pets of CATS and DOGS into a linked list that accepts Pets. I want to find the last index a DOG via:

```
        private Pet dequeueDog() {
        int locationDog = linkedList.lastIndexOf(DOG);
        return linkedList.remove(locationDog);
    }
```

Is it possible to do so? To reference an object by the type of object it is?

Comment: No. You can iterate the list backwards, and test if the object is a reference of that type - but `List` doesn't have a built-in method to do it.

Comment: Fantastic. I was actually trying to ask if you could test if the object is a reference of a type! Put as answer so I can mark this solved? Using getclass().

Comment: @lawonga Or instanceof.

Comment: Such container / access method (indexed by type) usually is named "Context". Read some theory

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's not a built-in method, and it's not a one-liner, but there's definitely ways to do it without explicit iteration.

Comment: Do you want to find the index of the last DOG; remove the last dog; return a boolean to indicate whether you removed the last DOG or get the last DOG object removed? I ask because your sample code could imply any of the above. `list.remove(object)` will return a boolean, not a Pet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java 8, you can `filter` out all non-`DOG`s to find the last dog then search for that:

```
private static Pet dequeueDog(LinkedList<Pet> linkedList) {

    List<Pet> dogList = linkedList.stream().filter(u -> u.getClass() == DOG.class).collect(Collectors.toList());
    int locationDog = linkedList.lastIndexOf(dogList.get(dogList.size()-1));
    return linkedList.remove(locationDog);
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/lnu7pC)'s an example where I put in two `DOG`s and three `CAT`s to the list, and receive the second `DOG` I put into the set.  You could extend this to remove the `n`th `DOG` by changing what you put into `dogList.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Java, but a bit ugly. Here is a method that will do it, given a list and a type that you want to search for.

```
public static <T> T getLastOfType(List<? super T> list, Class<T> type) {
    Object[] arr = list.toArray();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == null) continue;

        if (type.isAssignableFrom(arr[i].getClass())) {
            return (T) arr[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is a little test of it in action: http://pastebin.com/yX1v6L9p (Note that the explicit type parameters aren't strictly needed.)

This works by utilizing generics and the Class method [isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) to check the types of the objects in the list against the desired type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `instanceof` like so.

```
package com.example;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {

    class Pet {
    }

    class CAT extends Pet {
    }

    class DOG extends Pet {
    }

    private Pet dequeueDog(List<Pet> linkedList) {
        int i = 0;
        Integer foundIndex = null;
        DOG found = null;
        for (Pet pet : linkedList) {
            if (pet instanceof DOG) {
                foundIndex = i;
                found = (DOG) pet;
            }
        }
        if (foundIndex != null) {
            linkedList.remove(foundIndex);
        }
        return found;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        DOG someDog = new DOG();
        CAT someCat = new CAT();
        assertEquals(someDog, dequeueDog(Arrays.asList(someCat, someDog, null, someDog, someCat)));
    }

}
```